# Platypus Droplet Text change

Tags: macos, python-2.7, platypus, droplet

I have created a Platypus app for my Python script. I am using 'Droplet' interface to provide input file to my script. However, I would like to modify the standard message 'Drop files here'. Is there anyway I can do that in Platypus?

Thanks
Vik